# Sikuli4Net cannot find server error

Tags: c#, selenium, sikuli

I am trying to use Sikuli4Net but I got this exception in line `screen.Wait(gmail);` :

```
System.Net.WebException: 
Unable to connect to the remote server
InnerException  {"No connection could be made because the 
target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080"} System.Exception 
{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 
127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Here is my code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.nz/");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern gmail = new 
Pattern(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + 
@"/images/gmail.PNG"));
screen.Wait(gmail);
screen.Click(gmail, true);
```

I also tried this code:

```
APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher(true);
launcher.Start();
```

that I got this exception again in line `launcher.Start();` :

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
The system cannot find the path specified
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Activate administrator and log-in as administrator. It will solve this problem

Comment: same problem here. i m logged how administrator.